# How to fix the ignorance of globe controls in Globe.gl in Next.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webgl-globe

I'm using react-globe.gl to create a globe object for my next.js website.
Everything works well apart from the manually set controls.

Here's my code for the component:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Globe = dynamic(import("react-globe.gl"), { ssr: false });

let size = 1250;
import data from "./Globe-data";

export default function GlobeJS(){

    return (
        <Globe
            width={size}
            height={size}
            hexPolygonsData={data.features}
            hexPolygonResolution={3}
            hexPolygonMargin={0.3}
            hexPolygonColor={() => "#ffffff"}
            backgroundColor="#000"
            atmosphereColor="#fff"

            controls = {{
                autoRotate: true,
                autoRotateSpeed: 0.4,
                enableZoom: false
            }}
        />
    )

}
```

The Globe by itself looks fine, however, it does not spin and zooming is still enabled, showing that the controls have been ignored. What have I done wrong here? All sources show that this code is supposed to work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, *controls()* is a method for *globeEl.current* as it returns an instance of Three.js's OrbitControls,
Now, all *autoRotate*, *autoRotateSpeed*, and *enableZoom* are properties of *globeEl.current.controls()*.

So, what you can do is to use *useRef()* and *useEffect()* to deal with this.
I am using React.js if the code below helps.

```
import React from 'react'
import Globe from 'react-globe.gl'
import continents from '../../public/custom.geo.json'
import earthImg from '../../public/earth.jpeg'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'


function About() {
  const globeEl = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    // Auto-rotate
    globeEl.current.controls().autoRotate = true;
    globeEl.current.controls().autoRotateSpeed = 1;
    globeEl.current.controls().enableZoom = false;
    globeEl.current.pointOfView({
      lat: 23.5,
      lng: 0,
      altitude: 2.5,
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div id='about'>
      <div className="hero">
        <div className="hero--text">
          <h1>From Concept to Creation</h1>
          <h4>Bridging the Gap Between Imagination and Reality</h4>
          <div className="hero--description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br></br>Voluptates reprehenderit totam delectus neque error ex numquam, sint dolorum! Aperiam, ipsum?
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="hero--globe">
          <Globe
            ref={globeEl}
            globeImageUrl={earthImg}
            // backgroundImageUrl="//unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/night-sky.png"
            backgroundColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            width={1150}
            height={1150}
            hexPolygonsData={continents.features}
            hexPolygonMargin={0.7}
            hexPolygonColor={() => 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'}

          />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```